# Formatting percentages using toLocaleString causes value to be multiplied by 100

Tags: javascript

I've been racking my head as to trying to understand why when using `Number.prototype.toLocaleString`, it is multiplying my number by 100.

```js
var num = 5;
alert(num + ' vs ' + num.toLocaleString('en-GB', { style: 'percent' }));
```

Reading through all the reference guides, I have not seen anything that suggests it should be.

Have I completely missed the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/2.0/#sec-13.2.1):

> If the value of numberFormat.[[style]] is "percent", let x be 100 × x.

it expects a number in the range of [0, 1] which then would be formated to something between 0% and 100%

Comment: The only place I hadn't look - makes sense but noticed the lack of documentation else where that assumed you'd know this. Of course, the first time you use it you would realise, but it meant I had to divide my values by 100 to use it :( thanks for this :)

Answer (score 1):

It's `percent` not `toLocaleString` that is causing this, and the reason is that the percentage is measured by numbers from `0` to `1` as `0%` to `100%`, so if you want `5%`, use :

```js
var num = .05;
alert(num + ' vs ' + num.toLocaleString('en-GB', { style: 'percent' }));
```

More @ [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: I had hit Mozilla's reference first but saw no mention of the 0-1 but thanks :)

Comment: Ur welcome. Anyway this system of `0-1` is kind of known in computer science, it's used a lot, and especially in percentages.

Answer (score 0):

As many other systems do, `toLocaleString`'s percent style *interprets 1 as 100 %*.

This is a common way of expressing percentages (such as [in probability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory) where a 100 % probability is `1`).

Comment: It wasn't documented in any of the references I had come across, so presumed that it took the number as is (as it does when formatting currency etc) - thanks though :)

Comment: @Gavin Indeed, I was super impressed at user2520818 finding the original spec. Deserves the checkmark for that find!